# localStorage.getItem('access_token') return undefined for login endpoint in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest

I'm learning Angular and tryng to make a authentication in my application, my interceptor don't get access_token from localStorage.
My form calls the method signIn (code bellow):

```
  signIn(user: User) {
     return this.http.post<any>(`${this.endpoint}/login`, user)
       .subscribe((res: any) => {
         console.log(res);
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.token)
        this.getUserProfile(res._id).subscribe((res) => {
         this.currentUser = res;
         this.router.navigate(['user-profile/' + res.msg._id]);
        })    
      })
  }
```

so my intercept don't get the access token (code bellow)

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken
            }
        });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

the method getToken() return localStorage.getItem('access_token'), when I debug my code in vscode the authToken value is undefined and res in signIn method return null, someone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are trying to get the token from local storage for the `/login` request also, but that itself sets the token and it doesn't set it in local storage yet.

You should not try to get the token for the login request in your interceptor, but for the other requests after login you should do that. So there should be control in your interceptor which basically checks the url and if it contains `/login` it shouldn't set token.

In addition, in the backend there should not be a authorization filter for the `/login` path.

Comment: I don't think you should separate the flow. Actually, you should(if your current code doesn't work and you don't own the backend), but that's not the problem because the backend shouldn't look for such a header on the `/login` endpoint.

Comment: @ALex Thanks, you are right that if there would be no filter for `/login` in the backend, even if `Authorization: Bearer undefined` is being sent to server because of `authToken is null`, we could expect that server would return a valid response. But as you said  server doesn't return a valid response so the `res is null`. Thus there should be no filter for `/login` in the backend also.